# I am very new to HAL and have issue using it

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, hal

trying to integrate hal into existing asp.net mvc webapi2 project.
I have wrapper object that is returne in every request from the api.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "error": false,
  "message": "OK",
  "status": "200",
  "data": [
```

here in data is the payload from the api request (if there is payload).
I am trying to include hal only in that object. - so only in the nested object so the response of api call will look like this:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new JsonResponse2<ChallengeViewModel>(resultViewModel));
[DataContract]
    public class JsonResponse2<T> where T : Representation
    {
        private MessageCode _messageCode;
        private string _messageString;

        public MessageCode MessageCode { get { return _messageCode; } }

        /// <summary>
        /// The version of the API
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The version.
        /// </value>
        [DataMember(Name = "version")]
        public string Version
        {
.....
  [DataMember(Name = "data")]
        public T Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            private set { data = value; }
        }
```

What is happening when searalizing data in the output is that I do not have the fields from hal serialized.
when I return data as 
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultViewModel); - without the wrapper around everything is good. Look at the library but do not want to change it if what I am missing is something very simple...

Here is the Representation I am trying to return

```
[DataContract]
    public class ChallengeViewModel : Representation
    {
      [DataMember]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
        public Guid CompetitionId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "requiredRank")]
        public int RequiredRank { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "totalEntries")]
        public int TotalEntrants { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public Guid ChallengeTypeId { get; set; }

        public override string Rel
        {
            get { return LinkTemplates.Configurations.Challenge.Rel; }
            set { }
        }
        public override string Href
        {
            get { return LinkTemplates.Configurations.Challenge.CreateLink(new { id = Id }).Href; }
            set { }
        }

        protected override void CreateHypermedia()
        {
            Links.Add(LinkTemplates.Configurations.GameConfig.CreateLink(new { id = Id }));
        }
    }
```

As I said works fine without the wrapper class in which I set some generic staff for each response.

So to recap

```
  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new JsonResponse2<ChallengeViewModel>(resultViewModel));
dosn't searlize well

  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultViewModel);
serializes well with the HAL properties
```

How can I make HAL to work in wrapped classes when response from API.

The library I am using for HAL is this https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/WebApi.Hal